# Django beginner define an index url and load the view

Tags: python, django

I am learning django and I am trying to add a new url to `'/'`

here is my **urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from blog import views as blog_views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$', blog_views.index),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and here is the index method from **blog/views**:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hey There")
```

But when I go to '/' route, I get a 404 response. It seems that it fails at import `from blog import views as blog_views` in **urls.py**.

What is going wrong?

Here is my project structure:

[image: proj_structure]

Here is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: If the code were actually failing, you'd be getting a 500 error, not a 404.  Edit `settings.py` to make sure `DEBUG=True`, then post the full error message here.

Comment: updated. Its another route, but for '/' the error is the same

Comment: In the question, you say you're going to `/` path, but the error message says you tried to go to `post/1` path.  Which is it?

Comment: Also, your `urls.py` does not contain a `post/` path, but Django says it tried that path, so this is not your actual code.  It's much harder to help when you show us different code than you're actually using.

Comment: updated the screenshot. I havent posted unimportant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django 2.x there is a path function instead of django's 1.x url function
the path function doesn't accept Regular Expressions it only accepts normal text 
So to make a url for the home page with path function you only need to write your url path like this :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', blog_views.index), # http://localhost/
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

read more about Django 2.x urls here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/

Comment: thank you very much! this solved my problem. I still have a small question, why '/' does not work and I have to put '' route instead?

Comment: on the documentation they says that "There’s no need to add a leading slash, because every URL has that"

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters